# 404 not found signalr

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

My Signalr was working perfectly, so after I finished up that portion of my task for this solution I moved onto other task.

It's been about 6 months since I work with that portion of my solution and now I'm running test and finalizing, re factoring, tiding up this huge solution. When I got to the Signalr portion of my re factoring I'm getting a 404 error.

I've tried to download the most resent and I get the rollback because my Jquery is already the latest, so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with Signalr portion of the install.

What should I look for or what should I do to get my previously working Signalr that is not working now to work?

I've made no changes what so ever to my Signalr related portion of my solution and I'm getting this error:

```
GET http://localhost:22773/signalr/negotiate?_=1383588717286 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: What is your version of SignalR? 
Check your packages.config and validate all SignalR packages are same version
Open Browser and go to http://localhost:22773/signalr/hubs to see if you get the autogenerated hubs javascript file

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error with that link. I forgot about that little way to check. But I guess sometime during the develop phase I've screwed something up. I tried to upgrade to the latest SignalR but it keeps rolling back saying I got the latest Jquery, lol JQuery. Do I need to uninstall the previous SignalR then re-install it? –

Comment: Anyone at all can help with this?

Comment: Yes, uninstall all SignalR packages and re-install